# Coma Cluster X-Ray Mass

Tags: specific-reference, galaxy-clusters

Does anyone have a reliable reference for the x-ray mass of the [Coma Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_Cluster)?  I've got a value of $3\times10^{13}\: M_⊙$ from Gursky's 1971 report. Anything more recent would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly better for Astronomy SE?

Comment: I don't think so, Red, this is all related to Cosmology; these values go into testing models such as LCDM and MOND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gas mass $(5.5 \pm 0.6) \times 10^{14} (H_0/50)^{-5/2} M_{\odot}$ within $5(H_0/50)^{-1}$ Mpc, where $H_0$ is the Hubble parameter in km/s per Mpc - [Hughes (1989)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1989ApJ...337...21H).

Or $(5.1 \pm 1.5) \times 10^{14} (H_0/50)^{-5/2} M_{\odot}$ within $5(H_0/50)^{-1}$ Mpc - [Briel et al. (1992)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1992A%26A...259L..31B).

Comment: Many thanks.  I'm surprised there's not a more recent estimate though.  Found lots of data for small clusters, but not this one.

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey The more recent X-ray satellites have smaller fields of view.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed this part.  Are you saying I need to take the value 5.1 e14 kg and multiply it by (70.5/50)^(5/2) to get the right mass within 5 *(70.5/50) Mpc?

Comment: Just to be clear.  The conclusion of Briel et al (1992) is that the mass of gas within 5 / (70.5/5) = 3.55 Mpc is (5.1e14 * (70.5/5)) 1.2 e15 kg?

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey The indices are -5/2 and -1. For H=70.5, it is a mass of 2.16e14 solar masses(!) within 3.55 Mpc.

Comment: OMGosh - I've been looking at these number so long I've gone blind.  Thanks!